# NSManagedObject's values suddenly going null

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am having issues with my application. In the `viewDidLoad` method the `_recipe` object will print out its values. However when the `addToFavourites` method is called the values of the `_recipe` object return null and I can't figure out why any help will be majorly appreciated.

Heres the class.

```
  #import "DetailViewController.h"
  #import "Recipe.h"
  #import "AppDelegate.h"

  @interface DetailViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation DetailViewController

  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
 }
   return self;
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   self.recipetitle.text = _recipe.title;

   self.recipeingrediants.text = _recipe.ingrediants;
   self.recipemethod.text = _recipe.method;

  NSString *str = self.recipe.img64;
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:0];

self.recipeimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
   NSLog(@"This is odd.. %@",_recipe.title);
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 - (IBAction)addToFavourites:(id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]     delegate] managedObjectContext];
Recipe *favourite = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:context];


[favourite setValue:self.recipe.title forKey:@"title"];
 [favourite setValue:_recipe.ingrediants forKey:@"ingrediants"];

NSLog(@"ERMM WHAT %@",_recipe.title);
 [favourite setValue:_recipe.method forKey:@"method"];
 [favourite setValue:_recipe.img64 forKey:@"img64"];
 [favourite setValue:_recipe.type forKey:@"type"];


NSError *err;
[context save:&err];

NSLog(@"SAVE FIRED");

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out! The reference to the `_recipe` was `weak`! Therefore when the `viewDidLoad` method ended the previous view got put on the heap. Due to the `_recipe` not having an extra reference count it too went on the heap!

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your solution. As soon as possible please mark as answered your response.

Comment: @flexaddicted No worries! Will do in 23 hours :)